# chown / chgrp from php vs python

Tags: php, apache, permissions, file-permissions, chown

I have two users on Ubuntu, *www-data* and *labor*, both are in the group *chiara*.
Both users can do

```
>chown :chiara some_file
>chgrp chiara some_file
```

I have a python `test.py` script that uses

```
import os
os.system('whoami')     # displays 'www-data' in both cases
res = os.system('chown :chiara some_file')
print res          # 0 when called from shell, 256 when called from php script
```

When I call this script as either user, it works properly.

However, when I call this script from a php script in apache

```
shell_exec('test.py')
```

it does *not* work - despite the displayed user is 'www-data'.
This problem persists if I change 'chmod' this into 'chgrp'.
Also, using `os.chown` does not work. Seems like a general permission problem to me...

---

EDIT: using subprocess.Popen in python, I could retrieve the error message 
 `changing group of '/absolute/path/to/some_file': Operation not permitted`

---

EDIT 2: I think of surrender on this question... in my specific application, "chmod 777" on the directories is sufficient (that works!). However, I'd just like to understand what went wrong.

Comment: How do you know that this is permission problem?  Do you see `access denied` error somewhere?

Comment: I just see that the return code is not 0, which indicates some "erroneous behavior", and that the group of the file is not altered (it *is* altered when I call the script directly from shell). I do not *know* if this is a permission problem ...

Comment: Do you specify `some_file` as absolute path, or just relative path?  It is possible that your current working directory is not what you expect.

Comment: Thanks - I used indeed relative path. But, I also checked this by (a) printing "pwd", and (b) just right now changed this into an absolute path. Didn't get better. Maybe apache on some mysterious ways prevents any invocation of "chown"?

Comment: OK.  Lets continue guessing.  What if `chown` utility is not in PATH?  Try specifying full path to `chown`, such as `/usr/sbin/chown`.

Comment: The full path is `/bin/chown` and `/bin/chgrp` - does not help.